# Get the DOM Table Object of a p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to get the DOM table object of a `p:dataTable`?

For instance :

```
<h:form id="myForm">
  <p:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{someBean.list}" var="item">
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your browser developer tool look at the html source that is generated on the server. In the resulting html of the above code, the given `id` of the `p:dataTable` is associated to a `<div>` wrapping the `<table>`. To retrieve the DOM table object just use :

```
var table = $( "#myForm\\:myTable:first table" )[0];
```

Using `\\:` to escape the colon and `[0]` to retrieve the DOM object.

Answer (score 0):

`$('table[id*=myTable]')[0]`

PF generates the element id based on the given id and the element location in the DOM tree (e.j. ' #formid:containerId:yourTableId '), so your element id may change each time you change the structure or the ids in the DOM tree. IMHO, your best option is to look for the element containing your given id inside the PF generated id. Just make sure not to give other element id that matches the pattern too (e.j. myTable2)